# Authorisation is constantly required for Data Studio Community Connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have built a community connector which connects to DoubleClickManager API to grab report links for me to later fetch. And it works! However, it (DBM API) constantly requires authorisation. Is this a normal behaviour?

I have not tried anything yet but I may say that in the code there is this interesting setPropertyStore() function which I think I am not using correctly.

```
function getOAuthService() {

  return OAuth2.createService('exampleService')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId('my_id')
    .setClientSecret('my_secret')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager');
};
```

I do not have any User Properties stored. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Your question is too vague and general. Give a shot browsing to the documentation ["Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs"](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will have a closer look at the documentation. However, I thought I was just following instructions on community connector's manual site. To be honest, I do not fully understand the whole OAUTH 2 authentication process yet.

Comment: Could it be that the **token** simply expires so soon? I need to **authorise again** to grab a new **token**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I was not doing anything wrong. It is simply a short-lived token (I think 1 hour). the workaround would be using this project: [link to a project](https://github.com/google/argon)